# How to solve the recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations

How to solve the following recurrence relation?

$T(n) = 1$ if $n=1$.

$T(n) = T(n-1)+T(n-2)+T(n-3)+....+T(1)$ if $n > 1$.

No clue about solving it. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: What is T(n-1)? Use this to simplify the recurrence.

Comment: Suggestion: Try to compute $T(n)$ for a few small $n$, observe a pattern and set up a hypothesis and use mathematical induction to prove it.

Comment: (y) answer = 2^n

Comment: Not exactly. $T(2) = T(1) = 1 \neq 4 = 2^2$.

Comment: yea 2^(n-2) if n>1

Answer (score 3):

Just to write it cleaner :
$$
\eqalign{
T_2 &= T_1 \cr
T_3 &= T_2+T_1 = 2T_2 \cr
T_4 &= T_3+T_2+T_1 = 2T_3 \cr
T_5 &= T_4+T_3+T_2+T_1 = 2T_4 \cr
&\cdots \cr
T_n &= T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}+\cdots +T_2+T_1 = 2T_{n-1} \cr
}
$$
Multiplying all of them, we get:
$$
\eqalign{
T_2 \cdot T_3 \cdot \cdots T_n &= 2^{n-2} \cdot T_1 \cdot T_2 \cdot \cdots T_{n-1} \cr
T_n &= 2^{n-2}T_1 = 2^{n-2} 
}
$$